# Any subdomain point to internal directory with .htaccess

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess, server

I was trying to run a few stackoverflow
solutions but none of them was working
for me

I want any subdomain would show the
content of the internal directory.

for example :

```
test.example.com
```

would take it's content from :

```
example.com/subdomains/test
```

just to clarify i **do not** want to
redirect to the internal directory
I still want it to appear as if it's
real subdomain so the URL should
remain

```
test.example.com
```

I tried:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/subdomains/%1
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you give and absolute URL with a scheme/host/port different from current, you force a redirect. This should work:

```
RewriteCond %{IS_SUBREQ} !true
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.example\.com
RewriteRule .* subdomains/%1/ [L,QSA]
```